# Wrong EFI System Partition GUID?

Tags: uefi

On a new GPT initialized disk (second PC disk) I created a FAT32 partition using gparted.  I want to use it as an EFI System Partition so I flagged it as boot. After that I checked the UUID using the gparted “partition information” option and it reported: **09B1-97A5**.  As far as I understand it should be **C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B**.

I also checked my running operative system disk (Ubuntu 14) and found that Gparted reports **EB78-9AD2** for my actual boot partition UUID. What exactly is gparted reporting as UUID on my EFI system partition and why it doesn’t match with the expected **C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B** ID?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO and should be migrated to Super User, but nevertheless: double-check that you’re running GPT, these short UUIDs might be inherent to the file system used and have nothing to do with the GPT entries.

Comment: I just flagged it for assistance to migrate it to askubuntu. I posted it here by mistake. I guess I should not duplicate the question there!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're confusing filesystem UUIDs with partition GUIDs. The former are stored within the filesystems and can be used in Linux's `/etc/fstab` file or by the `mount` command via the `UUID=` parameter. (Despite the "UUID" name, they aren't always true UUIDs. FAT doesn't use UUIDs, for instance, so for FAT, the serial number is used instead of a UUID.) These UUIDs should be unique for any given filesystem, although cloned filesystems might have duplicated UUIDs.

Partition GUIDs, by contrast, are available only on GPT disks. There are actually two GUIDs associated with a partition:

- A type code GUID, which is what the C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B figure is. That particular GUID identifies an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) This is equivalent to the one-byte partition type codes of an MBR disk.
- A partition's unique GUID, which, like a filesystem UUID, should be unique to any particular partition. The EFI uses this GUID internally, and some versions of Linux utilities enable you to use it much like a filesystem UUID, but using the `PARTUUID=` label rather than `UUID=`.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. As suggested by a poster the UUIDs on GParted have nothing to do with GPT. I actually found the right GUID using:  sudo gdisk /dev/sda. After that I used the option "i"